# Laravel problems with redirect

Tags: laravel

So I am working on a laravel project and I want that if a user types in their order code, the order will show up with the details. For some reason, the order code doesn't get through the if statement, because I get the output 'Order not found.' all the time, even if I type in an order code that is present in my orders table.

**TrackController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Order;

class TrackController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('track.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $order = Order::where('code', $id)->first();
        return view('track.show',[
            'order' => $order
        ]);
    }

    public function redirect(Request $request)
    {
        $orderCode = $request->input('order-track-id');
        $order = Order::where('code', $orderCode)->first();
        if(!$order){
            return redirect('/track')->with('error', 'Order not found.');
        }else{
            return redirect('/track/' . $order->code);
       }
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/track', 'TrackController@index');
Route::post('/track/redirect', 'TrackController@redirect');
Route::get('/track/{id}', 'TrackController@show');
```

**track.index**

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content center">
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TrackController@redirect', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
            {!! csrf_field() !!}
            <input type="number" name="input-order-track-id" id="order-track-id">
            {{ Form::button('Track', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary'] )  }}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

What am I doing wrong and why isn't my function putting me through to the show function in the TrackController?

Comment: your input field is named `input-order-track-id` not `order-track-id`

Comment: How this little mistake gave me such a headache.. Thanks so much for checking my code and providing me this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your redirect controller function.

```html
public function redirect(Request $request)
    {
        $orderCode = $request->input('input-order-track-id');
        $orders = Order::where('code', $orderCode)->get();
        if($orders->isEmpty()){
            return redirect('/track')->with('error', 'Order not found.');
        }else{
        $order = Order::where('code', $orderCode)->first();
        
            return redirect('/track/' . $order->code);
       }
    }
```